# What is the value of $\mu_0$ and $\kappa_0 $in $N(\mu_0,\sigma / \kappa_0)$?

Tags: bayesian, mathematical-statistics

In a Bayesian analysis I want to sample $\sigma \sim \text{inverse-Wishart}(\nu_0,M)$ where $\nu_0$ is the degrees of freedom, equal to dimension+1 and $M$ is a scalar matrix

Then I will sample the $\mu$ from  $\mu|\sigma \sim N(\mu_0,\sigma/\kappa_0)$.
My question is, what is the value of $\mu_0$ and $\kappa_0$  and how can I determine my dimensions in the inverse-Wishart?

Answer (score 1):

$\mu_0$ is the prior mean and $\kappa_0$ is the number of prior measurements, both on the $\sigma$ scale. The dimensions refer to the number of dimensions in the $d \times d$ M matrix which is also the number of dimensions/variables in the multivariate Inverse-Wishart distribution.

A basic noninformative prior distribution for the Inverse-Wishart distribution would be

$M = I = d \times d$ Identity matrix

$\nu_0 = d+1$

This gives noninformative marginal distributions, but the joint distribution is not uniform however. A noninformative $\kappa_0$ can be chosen to create a very large variance. $\mu_0$ would depend on the domain of your problem.

Thoughts on how to create informative priors would require more information about your problem.

More details can be found in section 3.6 of Gelman's Bayesian Data Analysis

Comment: great information thank you . but what about the value of d in the identity matrix how can you determine this value

Comment: @Sonayu d is the number of dimensions/variables in the multivariate Inverse-Wishart distribution

Comment: I have a system of differential equations have three variables and I want to sample from the posterior but because I have noninformative prior I will sample the sigma then the mu then the posterior. In this case the d will equal to 3 ?

Comment: @Sonayu Unfortunately, I haven't used MCMC to solve differential equations. But if there are 3 variables/parameters  that you want posteriors for, then yes $d=3$